# Check with VBA if AllowEditRanges are Password protected

Tags: excel, vba

How can one Check with VBA if **AllowEditRanges are Password protected?**
Some of the AllowEditRanges might have a user, some haven't.
Excel can figure it out by making a check mark by *Paste permissions information into a new workbook*

But I don't know how to do it with VBA.

[image]